# Error when trying to load a page

Tags: c#, .net, localization

I have this page in .NET/C# and it's throwing the following error -

Could not parse the language 'en-BM'. Note that a custom language name must be on the form: isoLanguageCode-isoRegionCode-customName. The language codes are two-letter ISO 639-1, and the regions codes are are two-letter ISO 3166. Also, customName must not exceed 8 characters in length. Valid example: en-US-East. For the full list of requirements, see: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx

I have no clue as to what this error is. It throws the error for a code line. What can I do to fix this or get around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible the CurrentCulture has been set to a non-standard value (ie a culture that isn't installed on the machine the app is running on) - i'd do a search through your solution for "en-BM" and find out if it's been set any where.  Maybe in web.config "globalization" section, or in code against Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture or Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture

Answer (score 1):

You might have some method that fail due to current culture of your machine. Try changing the current thread culture that suite you.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```